# DUVMIF Fortran Error 1 Computer Rounding Error

Tags: fortran

I using DUVMIF to estimate the minimum of my objective function, defined in the following code block:

```
!********************************************************************************************
subroutine optimize(b_next,gn_value, h_value,v_value,a_initial2,b_initial2,i_default_global2)

USE GLOBAL
USE UVMIF_INT

implicit none

REAL(8),INTENT(IN)::a_initial2,b_initial2
INTEGER,INTENT(IN)::i_default_global2

REAL(8),INTENT(OUT)::b_next,gn_value,h_value,v_value

INTEGER, PARAMETER::num=100,XACC = 1d-4,MAXFN = 1000

integer :: i,t, d, index_opt, index_vector(1) ,index_opt2       
REAL(8) :: new_value, old_value,old_value2, b, q,vector(nb),&
                    b_next_grid(num), STEP, BOUND, b_next_guess
real(8)::b_next_inf,b_next_sup 
EXTERNAL  DUVMIF

REAL(8)::value1,value2

    b_next_inf = bmin 
    b_next_sup = -0.48d0 

old_value = 10d+33
do i=1,num 

   b_next_grid(i) = b_next_inf + (b_next_sup - b_next_inf) * (i-1)/ (num - 1)
   new_value = objective_fun2(b_next_grid(i))
   if (new_value <= old_value) then
      index_opt = i
      b_next_guess = b_next_grid(i)
      old_value = new_value
   end if
      if ((DABS(old_value-new_value) <= 1d-6)) then
      index_opt2 = i
      old_value2 = new_value
   end if

end do

STEP = (b_next_grid(2) - b_next_grid(1))*0.5
BOUND = EXP(amax)

PRINT*,'initial guess obtained'
PRINT*,' '
IF (old_value.GE.1d5) THEN
    b_next = 0d0
    gn_value=0d0
    h_value=0d0
    v_value = -old_value
ELSEIF (((DABS(old_value2 - old_value)) < 1d-6).AND.(index_opt2.NE.index_opt)) THEN        
    b_next  = b_next_grid(index_opt2)
    call objective_fun(b_next,gn_value,h_value,v_value,a_initial2,b_initial2,i_default_global2)
    v_value=-v_value
ELSE        

    call DUVMIF(objective_fun2, b_next_guess, STEP, BOUND, XACC, MAXFN, b_next)
        call objective_fun(b_next,gn_value,h_value,v_value,a_initial2,b_initial2,i_default_global2)
        v_value = -v_value
end if

CONTAINS

REAL(8) FUNCTION objective_fun2(x)

REAL(8),INTENT(IN)::x
REAL(8)::xgn,xh,xvalue

CALL objective_fun(x,xgn,xh,xvalue,a_initial2,b_initial2,i_default_global2)

objective_fun2 = xvalue

END FUNCTION
end subroutine
!*******************************************************************************************
```

However, despite the function being flat and DUVMIF seeming to find a minimum, I am receiving an error 1 from using DUVMIF, see the following output:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezyTa.png)

I am unsure why this error is occurring as it seems DUVMIF has arrived in a reasonably precise neighborhood. I am new to Fortran and any guidance is appreciate.

Thanks.

I have tried altering the arguments of DUVMIF to use different thresholds of accuracy and it seems to not resolve the issue. I am expecting DUVMIF to settle in the region described in the last five rows of the output in the image posted before throwing the error.

Comment: Please never share error messages as pictures. Copy the full output and paste it **as text**. It is really important. Be aware that you received a *warning*, not an *error*. Also please understand that this seems like a very domain-specific problem that may be answerable only by the author of that code or by some other expert in that code. Few people here will know what `DUVMIF` is (I do not).

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Looks like it's a line search algorithm https://help.imsl.com/fortran/6.0/math/default.htm?turl=uvmif.htm . And you're right, it's more a warning message than an error message, and the word "error" that is printed in the output is misleading. This is even more an informational message than a true warning: at some point, this kind of algorithm is always limited by the machine precision (and this has nothing to do with Fortran).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error codes for the UVMIF routines from the IMSL library are in the manual page https://help.imsl.com/fortran/6.0/math/uvmif.htm linked in the comments section by PierU. Please note that they are described as "Informational errors":

```
Informational errors

Type   Code

3      1        Computer rounding errors prevent further refinement of X.

3      2        The final value of X is at a bound. The minimum is probably beyond the bound.

4      3        The number of function evaluations has exceeded MAXFN.
```

In this case for *"Computer rounding errors prevent further refinement of X."* it simply means that the algorithm cannot get any more refined value of X. If you apply the algorithm to get a new value, you will get the same value. What you get is the final answer from the algorithm and you will not get anything more precise unless you get a version of the subroutine with a higher floating point precision. The library offers single and double precision and since you are already using double precision, there is no higher precision version available.